# Link directly to expanded jQuery summarize box

Tags: jquery, html, expander

I'm using the summarize jQuery plugin by Karl Swedberg ( http://jjnursingnotes.com/DEC12/jquery.summarize.js ) to contain newsletter articles ( http://jjnursingnotes.com/DEC12/ ) and would like to link to each of these articles externally. Simply giving the elements a link name #001 isn't working, because I want the box to expand automatically when the link is clicked.

Currently, the links I'm using look like this:

```
<a href="http://jjnursingnotes.com/DEC12?section=01">
```

...and the div layers look like this:

```
<div class="expandable" id="sect01">
```

...and the javascript I'm using looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Redirect to Appropriate Section
    var urlParams = {};
    (function() {
        var match,
        pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function(s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
        query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

        while(match = search.exec(query))
            urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
    })();

    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(urlParams['section'] != '') {
            $("#sect" + urlParams['section']).find(".read-more a").click();
            $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: $("#sect" + urlParams['section']).offset().top}, 500);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Problem is that this just isn't working at all and I'm not sure why! Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: what does console.log(ulParams['section']) or alert(ulParams['section']) say, actually? why isn't #001 or similar not suitable for you? if you add a return false to your jquery script, you can use them...

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, they were included in the original script provided by Karl Swedberg. #001 isn't working because there is nothing in the link to tell the jquery box to expand.